# Detect via ExternalInterface when swf player ready to play

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my .fla file I include external actionscript file as indicated in the instruction file

```
import xxx.xxx.xxx.sound.MP3Player;

var mp3Player:MP3Player = new MP3Player();
addChild(mp3Player);
```

Now I'd like to use his loadMp3 function

```
/**
* Start loading the mp3 file.
*/
private function loadMP3():void {

mp3.load(new URLRequest(MP3_URL));
mp3.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
channel = mp3.play();
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete, false, 0,    true);            
_isPlaying = true;
}
```

to discover when the mp3 fully loaded and ready to play sound
via ExternalInterface function.

how could I do? thanks

FULL CLASS

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx.sound {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class MP3Player extends MovieClip {

    // Location of the config xml file
    public static const CONFIG_XML_URL:String = "xml/config.xml";

    // URL of the mp3 file
    public static var MP3_URL:String = "mp3/track.mp3";

    // Main color for the mp3 player
    public static var MAIN_COLOR:uint = 0xFF0000;

    // An XMLLoader to load the configuration file
    private var xmlLoader:XMLLoader;

    // Sound object to be played
    private var mp3:Sound = new Sound();

    // A sound channel to play the sound object
    private var channel:SoundChannel;

    // Holds the pause position
    private var pausePos:Number;

    // A byte array to read spectrum
    private var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    // Indicates whether the mp3 player is playing or not.
    private var _isPlaying:Boolean = false;

    // Holds the previous label color
    private var _prevColor:uint;        

    public function MP3Player() {

        // Initialize the player
        init();

    }

    /**
     * Initializes the player.
     */
    private function init():void {

        // Use as a button
        useHandCursor = true;
        buttonMode = true;
        mouseChildren = false;
        equalizer.alpha = 0;

        // Add necessary event listeners
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut, false, 0, true);
        loadConfig();

    }

    /**
     * Sets the color of the player to the given parameter.
     */
    public function setColor(color:uint):void {

        MAIN_COLOR = color;

        // Change the color of the equalizer
        var colorTransform:ColorTransform = equalizer.transform.colorTransform;
        colorTransform.color = MAIN_COLOR;
        equalizer.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;

    }


    /**
     * Loads the configuration file to the memory.
     */
    private function loadConfig() {

        // Start loading the config.xml file
        xmlLoader = new XMLLoader(CONFIG_XML_URL);
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(XMLLoader.XML_LOADED, onXMLLoaded);
        xmlLoader.load();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the xml file is loaded to the memory.
     */
    private function onXMLLoaded(evt:Event):void {

        // Get configuration parameters
        var xml:XML = xmlLoader.getXML();
        MP3_URL = xml.@mp3URL;
        MAIN_COLOR = xml.@color;

        // Change the color of the equalizer
        equalizer.alpha = 1;
        setColor(MAIN_COLOR);

        // Start loading the mp3
        loadMP3();

    }

    /**
     * Start loading the mp3 file.
     */
    private function loadMP3():void {

        mp3.load(new URLRequest(MP3_URL));
        mp3.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
        channel = mp3.play();
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete, false, 0, true);            
        _isPlaying = true;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called whenever a new enter frame event occurs.
     */
    private function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void {

        try {
            SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, true, 0);
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }

        equalizer.update(bytes);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when playing the sound is finished.
     */
    private function onSoundComplete(evt:Event):void {

        // Loop
        channel = mp3.play();
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete, false, 0, true);
        _isPlaying = true;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the mouse is over the mp3 player.
     */
    private function onMouseOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {

        // Change the color of the equalizer
        _prevColor = label.textColor;
        label.textColor = MAIN_COLOR;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the mouse leaves the mp3 player.
     */
    private function onMouseOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {

        label.textColor = _prevColor;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the mouse is clicked on the mp3 player.
     */
    private function onMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void {

        if (_isPlaying) {
            pausePos = channel.position;
            channel.stop();
            _isPlaying = false;
            label.text = "MUSIC OFF";               
        } else {
            channel = mp3.play(pausePos);
            channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete, false, 0, true);
            _isPlaying = true;
            label.text = "MUSIC ON";
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called if an IO error occurs.
     */
    private function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Where do you define `mp3` and `channel`? And does your `Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` give a callback when the MP3 is ready to play? Where did you find the MP3Player class?

Comment: I found the class in the flash project that I purchased.

Comment: Hmm maybe you should have a look at that class, see if there are events that get triggered when the MP3 is done loading. But Im guessing it is the `Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` function.

Comment: I post full class. Can U help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to discover when your MP3 is fully loaded you can add the following lines to your `loadMP3()` function:

```
mp3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
```

And you should this function too.

```
private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
    // This will call a JavaScript function
    ExternalInterface.call('toJS');
}
```

In order to make the `ExternalInterface` to work your should import the Class:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

Than in your HTML you should add a function with the same name 'toJS' in order to get your callback in JavaScript. (You can call this function whatever you want).

Comment: Thanks very much! I've only a little problem when compiling (see my post).

Comment: That only happens if you try it locally. If you put this online you won't have that problem. For now you have to open up 'settings' and add `c:/` to your trusted pages. See http://www.adobe.com/security/flashplayer/articles/localcontent/ for more information about that

Comment: You have been very kind to help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry but I realized that there is a problem with some browsers. How could I do to make a ExternalInterface call when the music starts to play?
thanks

Comment: What problems are you encountering? What browser(s)?

Comment: I insert in my html a overlay to hide the content until it is called the loading complete. In chrome on win 7 starts playing the music before the sound is being fully loaded and that ExternalInterface call JS for load complete. In practice, the music starts while the html content is still hidden by the overlay div.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the code that was suggested to me by putvande.

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx.sound {
..
..
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

..
..

/**
* Start loading the mp3 file.
*/
private function loadMP3():void {

  mp3.load(new URLRequest(MP3_URL)); 
  mp3.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
  channel = mp3.play();
  channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundComplete, false, 0, true);          
 _isPlaying = true;

// Load complete function
mp3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
}

/**
* This method is called when load complete and sent call to js.
*/
private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
  // This will call a JavaScript function
  if (ExternalInterface.available)
  {
    ExternalInterface.call("loadedCallback");
  }
}
..
..
```

this solution works perfectly, but I would also solve the problem that occurs when compiling the swf and I get this message (once in the public html page is not displayed)

[image]

how can I fix this warning message? Thanks!